# RSpec api json recovers html instead of json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

Context:
I have created a timesheet, I want to test the CRUD of it with the json api, but when I launch the test in the console it returns me an error indicating the webpacker can't find the file.
Here is my code to rspec test the creation of a timesheet :

```
    it 'Create timesheet' do
        timesheet = {
            start_date: Date.new(2023,1,1), 
            end_date: Date.new(2023,1,31)
        }
        sign_in_as_a_valid_user
        post "/timesheets.json", headers: headers, params: timesheet, as: :json
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
        json_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
        byebug
        expect(json_response['start_date']).to eq(2023,1,1)
        expect(json_response['end_date']).to eq(2023,1,31)
    end
```

when I run the test in the console, it returns the following error :

```
1) Api Create timesheet
     Failure/Error: <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', defer: true %>
     
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       Webpacker can't find application.js in /home/yir/Documents/workspace/projet1/alpha/public/packs-test/manifest.json. Possible causes:
       1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
          unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
       2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
       3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
       4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
       Your manifest contains:
       {
       }
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?
Thank you!

Edit 18/04/2023 :

Here is the code of the timesheet controller :

```
class TimesheetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_timesheet, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  # GET /timesheets or /timesheets.json
  def index
    @timesheets = Timesheet.order(start_date: :asc)
  end

  # GET /timesheets/1 or /timesheets/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /timesheets/new
  def new
    @timesheet = Timesheet.new
    my_date = Date.today
    @days = my_date.beginning_of_month.upto(my_date.end_of_month)
  end

  # GET /timesheets/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /timesheets or /timesheets.json
  def create

    @timesheet = Timesheet.new(timesheet_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @timesheet.save
        format.html { redirect_to @timesheet, notice: "Timesheet was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @timesheet }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @timesheet.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /timesheets/1 or /timesheets/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @timesheet.update(timesheet_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @timesheet, notice: "Timesheet was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @timesheet }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @timesheet.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /timesheets/1 or /timesheets/1.json
  def destroy
    @timesheet.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to timesheets_url, notice: "Timesheet was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_timesheet
      @timesheet = Timesheet.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def timesheet_params
      params.require(:timesheet).permit(:month, :start_date, :end_date)
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you walk through the steps in the Error to diagnose the cause? Also looks like you are not calling an API endpoint.

Comment: @dbugger if you want to talk about the controller I added the code in the article, I also detailed a bit the context

Comment: your json response is rendering html -- and your webpack isn't set up properly

Comment: maybe you should use blueprints or other library to return datas

Comment: I would like it to return json, there is a problem with the webpack because it returns html. Do you know how to make it return json? @dbugger

Comment: when you render :show -- you are rendering html -- render json to return json

Comment: [You should not *force* a tag into your title.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for.